# How should a JSONP response be formed in Go using http.ResponseWriter?

Tags: go, jsonp

I'm developing an API that accepts JSONP requests in Go. I can serialize a struct into JSON and return it, but wrapping the JSON in padding, or the callback function, is a little awkward, since the argument to `Write()` needs to be a byte slice:

```
callback := req.FormValue("callback")

// ...

jsonBytes, _ := json.Marshal(resp)
if callback != "" {
    jsonStr := callback + "(" + string(jsonBytes) + ")"
    jsonBytes = []byte(jsonStr)
}
responseWriter.Write(jsonBytes)
```

I suppose I will encapsulate this in some function. Mostly I find the string/[]byte conversion funky. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fmt.Fprintf` to simplify it:

```
if callback != "" {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s(%s)", callback, jsonBytes)
} else {
    w.Write(jsonBytes)
}
```

Or if you only want to write in one place:

```
jsonBytes = []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s(%s)", callback, jsonBytes))
```

Comment: `fmt.Sprintf` rather than `fmt.Printf` I think you meant

Comment: This seems sufficiently simple! For some reason Sprintf didn't come to my mind.